# Angular: Browser is redirecting to diffrent backend ports

Tags: angular, nginx, web, frontend, backend

We have angular front end app, which makes backend calls to following endponts

```
      https://backend.com/login:3000
      https://backend.com/payment:3001
      https://backend.com/reviews:3002
```

Above endpoints are calling in fron-end (Angular) and we are using httpclient(angular) module for making backend calls.

End users are making requests from browser "https://fronend.com:443"

After they hit any tab/url like login, payment. Requests are redirecting from end user browser to backend api like https://backend.com/login:3000.

But expectations is all request should go to fronend server and port 443 only. fronend should make calls and resonpond back.

can we achive thin in frontend (angular) code level ? if yes please suggest with some examples

if code side is not recommended, do we have to place any nginx/reverse proxies to redirect requests like below

```
   end user-request -> fronend -> nginx with 443-> url redirection to backend url
```

or any other suggestions would be also fine.

Comment: from the angular app you should do request to `https://backend.com/` (no port needed since 443 is default).
Then you need to setup nginx in order to redirect to the correct port depending on the URL. This is not really an angular or frontend question but a Backend/NGINX question

Comment: ok, then nginx/some proxy  is must needed in oder to achive it right?

Comment: yes, this is exactly one of the purposes of NGINX